# Get search results for terms that are not part of the table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML table with a search function that works well. However, my search function only finds the results based on the existing table data. I am trying to show results for terms that aren't in the table. I am able to do this but with limited success.

As an example, if I search for "Apple Banana" (text that is **not** part of my table), the results are the same as if I searched for "ABC" (text that is part of my table). See my table below for example.

The problem is, I only get results after searching the entire term "Apple Banana". Is there a way to search for "App" or "Ban" (not exact match but contains) and still get the results? If using an object is not the best approach, I am open to any other suggestions. Note that the HTML table is generated automatically by the Content Management System and I am not able to manipulate it. I can update JavaScript or CSS file.

```js
const obj = {
  'Apple Banana':'ABC',
};
function myFunction() {
  let userInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  if(obj[userInput]) userInput = obj[userInput];
  userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
  const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
  for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    const rowTextContent = tableRows[i].innerText.toUpperCase();
    tableRows[i].style.display = rowTextContent.toUpperCase().includes(userInput) ? "" : "none";
  }
}
```

```css
table.table_brdr td {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border: none;
}

table.table_brdr th {
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  color: black;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color#D3D3D3;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search forms list" title="Search forms list"></p>
<table class="table_brdr" id="myTable">
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th><strong>Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>abc</td>
<td>xyz</td>
<td>03/30/2017</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>test12</td>
<td>https://www.yahoo.com/ </td>
<td>03/30/2017</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th> New Column</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>abctd <td>
<td>09/30/2019</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th> New Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>abctd </td>
<td>06/30/2019</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed up your js a a little bit. I used 2d array of values to search for and then filtered one out. Hope it helps.

```js
// array of values to serach for
let values = [
    ['ABC', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Apple Banana'],
    ['test12', 'otherSearch']
]

// convert all values to upperCase or simply declare them upperCase in array
values = values.map(arr => arr.map(v => v.toUpperCase()))

function myFunction() {
  let userInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase();
  
  // filter for array with user input and desired phrases
  const filtered = values.filter(arr => {
    return arr.some(v => v.includes(userInput))

  }).flat()
  
  const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
  for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    const rowTextContent = tableRows[i].innerText.toUpperCase();
    tableRows[i].style.display = filtered.some(v => rowTextContent.includes(v)) ? "" : "none";
  }
}
```

```css
table.table_brdr td {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border: none;
}

table.table_brdr th {
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  color: black;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search forms list" title="Search forms list"></p>
<table class="table_brdr" id="myTable">
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th>Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>abc</td>
<td>xyz</td>
<td>03/30/2017</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>test12</td>
<td>https://www.yahoo.com/ </td>
<td>03/30/2017</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th> New Column</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>abctd <td>
<td>09/30/2019</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th> New Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>abctd </td>
<td>06/30/2019</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: just add Apple Banana to array

Comment: Now I am not getting search results for terms that are in the table. Example "John" or yahoo

Comment: You don't get them beacuse they are not in the array. The whole idea of my solution is to add an array with values to search for in the table with added custom key words. If you want to search for 'John', add new array with value john inside 'values' and then if you want for example show jonh when user types 'pie' add 'pie' in the same array as 'John'. With this solution you can even combine searches with common keyword.

Comment: If you don't like that you need to add values that are present in the table in order to search for them, you can for example add an if at the end of the loop to check for userInput like you have in your question.